# gcloud docker documentation might need an update

Tags: docker, gcloud

https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pulling

Shouldnt `gcloud docker pull -- gcr.io/your-project-id/example-image` be
`gcloud docker -- pull gcr.io/your-project-id/example-image`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this! I've kicked off a process to fix it up; the site should be updated in a day or so.

In general, you should use the on-site feedback buttons (the star ratings that appear when you're logged-in) to report issues with the documentation, as this is off-topic for Stack Overflow.